# Getting multiple ids from a son object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am trying to get multiple ids from a JSON object and use them in useffect.

I cannot figure out how to join each track.id with a comma separating them to make the api call.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWV1x.png

^^What the JSON looks like

````
useEffect(() => {

        console.log(track)


        fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks?ids=' + track.id, {
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token }
        }).then(response => response.json())

            .then((data) => {
                console.log('Spotify Api Call - Music Page', data)
                const tranformedTracks = data.tracks.map(trackData => {
                    console.log(trackData)
                    return {
                        albumCover: trackData.album.images[0].url,
                        trackName: trackData.name,
                        artistName: trackData.album.artists[0].name,
                    };
                });
                setTopTracks(tranformedTracks);
                setTracksLoaded(true);
            });

    }, []);```
````

Comment: `tracks.map((track) => track.id).join(',')`?

Comment: Alternative from the answer above, you could use array reduce, ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

`data.tracks.reduce((prev, curr) => prev ? prev + "," + curr.id : curr.id, "")`

Comment: Thanks @dave I was trying for ages and your solution was the first I tried and worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map function to get all ids and the use join method to join them with comma and your solution is

```
let ids = trackData.map((track) => track.id).join(",")
console.log(ids) // Output : 1,2,3,4 :)
```